# How to get the work-dir of tomcat ApplicationContextFacade

Tags: tomcat, jboss

i have JBoss and Tomcat, i like to make one portable webapp for both.

On JBoss i use the jboss.server.data.dir-property to store websessions.
On Tomcat id like to use the /work/-dir. But how to get the work-dir?

I just have a **ApplicationContextFacade**-instance on tomcat. Is it possible to get the work-dir? I looked around, found the .getWorkDir/.getWorkPath, that looks like the method i lookd for. But therefore i need an instance of Context.

```
1 public static String getPath(EventObject session) {
2   String path=System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir");
3   
4   if (path == null && session.getSource() instanceof ApplicationContextFacade) {
5       ApplicationContextFacade acf = (ApplicationContextFacade) session
6               .getSource();
7       
8       path = acf.getWorkDir();
9
10  }
11  return path;
12}
```

(line 8 doesnt work)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something that is part of the servlet API:

```
java.io.File tmpDir = ServletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
```

On Tomcat, this gets you a `File` object that points to `$CATALINA_BASE/work/[service[/[engine]/[context]`.